# How often can I divide a number until I hit a certain limit.

Tags: recurrence-relations, exponential-function, divisibility, recursive-algorithms

I'm have an algorithm that can solve a certain problem in a specific number of steps.

Since this algorithm is recursive I'm unsure how to describe it mathematically.

Generally speaking the algorithm roughly follows the recession: a(n+1) = 3a(n)-1 and the closest equation I could find for this was y = 0.5*(3 + e^(1.09861*I)) (Using fitting with gnuplot).

Roughly simplified, the complexity of solving my problem for a specific value "I" depends on how often I can divide "I" by 3 ((I-1/3) to be exact) until I hit a number <= 5.

So I am searching for a mathematical way to express "Number of times I can divide "I" by 3.

The data below shows the exact complexities.
(For an input of I = 6, the complexity is N^2, for I = 15, it's N^3, etc)

```
2   6
3   15
4   42
5   123
6   366
7   1095
8   3282
9   9843
10  29526
```

Comment: The introduction is not super clear.

Comment: Dividing by $3$ $n$ times is the same as dividing by $3^n$

Comment: @Arnaud i have added some additional data

Comment: @user2524707 It is not enoug: what is I, what is y, what is a , what are each column of your array? what is n, what is N?

Comment: After I gave wolfram alpha the data of the second column, it gave me "a(n+1) = 3a(n)-1" as the recession. I believe a(n) are the results of the previous calculation.
Calculating 3*(3*a(n)-1)-1 where I add 3 * a(n) -1 n times. (until n reaches 1 and it is (3*(3*1-1)-1)

Comment: err... you mean that the first column is n and the second is a(n) and that a(n+1) = 3(a(n)-1) = 3a(n)-3, right?

Comment: btw there is a stadard solution to this recursion formula, expressing a(n) as a linear combination of a constant and of 3^n

Comment: Yes, it could be expressed similar to 3 + 3^1 + 3^2 + 3^3 + 3^4 for n times.
So 3 + Sum(3^n)

Comment: $I$ or $I-1/3$ ?? That makes a difference.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $I-1/3$. I had simplified it to 3 in the question since I thought I could deduce the exact one from the simplified example.

Comment: @Arnaud $1 + \sum_{n=0}^I(3^n))$ is the actual solution I was looking for, since you proposed it, could you write an answer that I can accept?

Comment: @user2524707 Sure, thanks, but I'm troubled because that is not obvious at all that that is the question that you were asking. Could you edit your OP?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if

$$a3^d\le i<a3^{d+1},$$ $d$ is the number of times you can divide by $3$ until the integer quotient is $a$.

Hence

$$\log_3 a+d\le\log_3i<\log_3a+d+1$$

and

$$d=\lfloor\log_3i-\log_3a\rfloor.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the log. Answer: $\mathrm{ceil}(\frac{\log(I-1/3)-\log 5}{\log 3})$.